# Unable to run hive command from another user on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hive

I have installed Apache Hive as hduser and am able to run that perfectly from my `hduser`.

I want to run that as command `hive -f someScript.sql` but I want to do that from some other user, say root. I am trying a command like

```
sudo -u hduser '/usr/local/hive/bin/hive -f test.sql'
```

The output I am getting is

```
sudo: /usr/local/hive/bin/hive -f test.sql: command not found
```

I have my user `hduser` in the list of sudoers as well if that helps.  I don't understand why this could be happening since hive has been properly added to the path and when I go via `su hduser` and then run it, this all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax of your command is incorrect. See this:

```
sudo -u hduser /usr/local/hive/bin/hive -f test.sql
```

Make sure that `hduser` has the **read** access to your test.sql file.

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is not correct (you are putting the entire query in quotes). Try this:

```
sudo -u hduser /usr/local/hive/bin/hive -f 'test.sql'
```